# Bootstrap-Notification não abre ao clicar no sino

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3

Eu uso "**Bootstrap Notification**" [aqui](https://skywalkapps.github.io/bootstrap-notifications/#application-notifications).

Eu apenas quero mostrar um tipo de dropdown ao clicar na notificação. Um exemplo a seguir:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o código a seguir acontece nada. Só mostra sino.

```
<div class="row nav1">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="top-menu" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Collapse navigation -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"> <a href="#">HOME</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">YOUR ACCOUNT</a>

          </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-notifications">
        <a href="#notifications-panel" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i data-count="2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell notification-icon"></i>
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-container">

            <div class="dropdown-toolbar">
                <div class="dropdown-toolbar-actions">
                    <a href="#">Mark all as read</a>
                </div>
                <h3 class="dropdown-toolbar-title">Notifications (2)</h3>
            </div><!-- /dropdown-toolbar -->

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="dropdown-footer text-center">
                <a href="#">View All</a>
            </div><!-- /dropdown-footer -->

        </div><!-- /dropdown-container -->
    </li><!-- /dropdown -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <!-- End navbar-inverse -->
</div>
```

Ou se preferir jsfiddle [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/ofz9Lgom/39/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione a classe `open` à tag referente ao sino.

```
<li class="dropdown dropdown-notifications open">
```

Em sequência, seria interessante utilizar JavaScript para adicionar e remover essa classe no evento de click.

Comment: mercador, veja: http://jsfiddle.net/ofz9Lgom/40/, tinha esquecido da classe `open`

Comment: Isso mesmo. Aliás, seu JavaScript pode ser simplificado: http://jsfiddle.net/pcwLpes4/

Comment: Só tenha certeza que usando o elemento e suas classes como seletor do evento de click não vai gerar conflitos no futuro. Talvez seja uma boa ideia usar um `id`.